# Incompressible Fluid and Sinks

Tags: fluid-dynamics

This question is pretty vague but we just learned about sources and sink in vector calculus.  I have read that most liquids are incompressible.  I am wondering how it is possible for fluid for be forced inward toward a sink if it is incompressible?  Doesn't it have to discharge or go up or down the axis of rotation of the origin.  I am assuming the sink means that a force field is compressing the gas, solid, liquid inwards and this means there would have to be compression.  I cannot seem to find any sources other than the one below that indicates "For fluid flows, a sink is a negative source and is a point of inward radial flow at which the fluid is considered to be absorbed or annihilated."

http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/SourceSinkMod.html

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the fluid just appears (vanishes) at a source (sink). In practice however there is always a conduit that will add or remove the fluid into the flow domain under consideration (of which the conduit is not a part). The inflow (outflow) of the fluid into the flow-domain is then modelled as a source (sink) without violating incompressibility constraint.

Comment: You might be interested to know that the equations of compressible potential flow can be rewritten as a Poisson equation with right-hand-side proportional to a source (sink) distribution. So-called "field-panel methods"  with numerical techniques similar to the panel methods of incompressible flow used to exist, but were not as computationally efficient as alternate procedures. (Nor could they as easily be made to model shock-waves in transonic flow cases,)